# Tkinter not working the first time it runs with withdraw()

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

I am trying to make a Tkinter script to select files through Windows File Explorer. I don't need the Tkinter window to show, just the File Explorer interface.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

window = tkinter.Tk()
#window.geometry("1x1")
window.withdraw()

def open_files():
    files = filedialog.askopenfiles(mode='r')
    global filenames
    filenames = [os.path.abspath(file.name) for file in files]
    window.destroy() # analysis:ignore #says "window" is undefined becasue of "del window" below

window.after(0, open_files)
window.mainloop()

del window
```

The first time I run this in Spyder, if `window.withdraw()` is not commented out, the console just shows `runfile(*my_file_name*)` and the code does... something... in the background, but nothing seems to actually happen. Nothing changes on-screen, but I cannot type in the console so I know the code is running.

If I open a new console tab and run the code with `window.withdraw()` commented out, everything works, and the Tkinter GUI is visible. If I *then* run this code *again* in the same tab, with `window.withdraw()` **not** commented out, then the code works as intended, with only the File Explorer window opening up, and the Tkinter GUI staying hidden. This is the case even if I click the "Remove all variables" button in Spyder, so as far as I understand the code is not saving any variables that allow it to run properly after the first time.

My question is, why does this code work the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. time I run it, but not the first time?

Comment: It probably interferes with spyder.

Comment: Try: `window.attributes('-alpha',0)` in combination with `window.overrideredirect(1)` instead of `window.withdraw()`. In addition out of curiosity, does `window.iconify()` behaves the same? Cause I guess not.

Comment: In order to see the `window` you must use `window.deiconify()`.

Comment: @Thingamabobs 
`window.attributes('-alpha',0)` in combination with `window.overrideredirect(1)` produces the same results as `window.withdraw()`.

`window.iconify()` opens both the Tkinter window and File Explorer, but they are minimized.

`window.attributes('-alpha',0)` in combination with `window.overrideredirect(0)` opens File Explorer. It is minimized the first time, but all subsequent times it becomes the top window, just as with `window.overrideredirect(1)`.

Comment: What about just `overrideredirect(1)`  and uncomment the window geometry. Does this work and is satisfying?

Comment: No, on the first run `window.overrideredirect(1)` just causes the code to freeze, as described above.

Answer (score 3):

I kept playing around, and changed `-alpha` to `alpha` and got this error:

```
TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window ?-alpha ?double?? ?-transparentcolor ?color?? ?-disabled ?bool?? ?-fullscreen ?bool?? ?-toolwindow ?bool?? ?-topmost ?bool??"
```

So I ended up changing `window.attributes('-alpha',0)` to `window.attributes('-topmost',True, '-alpha',0)`, and this works! It brings up File Explorer on the first run without showing the Tkinter window. Thank you @Thingamabobs for your help.

My final code is:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.attributes('-topmost',True, '-alpha',0)

filenames = [os.path.abspath(file.name) for file in filedialog.askopenfiles(mode='r')]

window.destroy()
del window
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution!

Comment: Worker wonders for me too, thanks!!